# How to solve concurrency issues in a React Native application?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, react-native, concurrency, thread-safety

Let's add a `<FlatList/>` into our application.

The first requirement we have is to render a predefined set of 5 items. We define a constant in our component, pass it into the list via the `data` prop and it works just fine...

... until we decide to store this data on a server and expose it via the API. OK, no problem, will fetch the data in our `componentDidMount()` method, put it into the state when it finishes loading, pass the state to the `data` prop and it also works just fine...

... until we notice that we have a huge delay before we can show the first item of the list. That is because the amount of data we're loading from the API grew significantly over time. Maybe now it is some REST resource collection consisting of thousands of items.

Naturally, we decide to implement a pagination in our API. And that is when the things start to get interesting... When do we load the next page of the resource collection? We reach out to the wonderful React Native API reference, examine the `FlatList` part of it, and figure out that it has a very handy `onEndReached` callback prop. Wonderful! Let's load the next page of our collection every time this callback is called! It would work as a charm...

... until you receive a bug report in your mail. In this report a user tells us that the data is not sorted properly in the list, that some items are duplicated and some items are just missing.

After a quick debugging we are able to reproduce the issue and figure out what causes it. Just set the `onEndReachedThreshold = { 5 }` and scroll the list very fast. `onEndReached` callback would fire asynchronously before the previous one has finished.

Inside our component, we have a variable `pageId` storing the last page ID we loaded. Each time the `onEndReachedThreshold` gets fired we use it to construct the next page URL and then increment it. The problem is that this method is called concurrently and the same value of `pageId` is used multiple times.

I used to do a bit of multithreading programming before, I've heard of mutexes, semaphores, and atomicity. I would like to be able to acquire an exclusive lock on the `pageId` to use it in this concurrent callback.

But after a quick Internet search, it seems that JS does not provide such tools out of the box. I found some libraries like [this one](https://github.com/DirtyHairy/async-mutex#readme) but it doesn't look like a good candidate for a dependency, it's not very actively developed, it's not made by a major vendor etc. Looks more like some hobby project.

The question is: what are the **industry-standard rock-solid** tools or patterns for thread-safe React Native programming? How can I solve the described concurrency issue in a React Native application?

Comment: Can you add your code? It seems weird for me that onEndReached get called before the previous one has finished. When you reach the end of your flatlist, there is no other end until your server send you the other items.

Comment: @FrancescoClementi imagine the user scrolling the list back and forth quickly. The event can get fired 10 times per second even though the list contents didn't change.

Comment: Did you try using another state to keep track if a request is loading and fire another request only if the last one is finished? Moreover you can keep track which request is fired and avoid to fire the same request after? Another solution if you are using axios is to use axios interceptors to code your use case.

Comment: @FrancescoClementi how do you suggest to set the state in a thread-safe way without any race conditions being possible? Two `onEndReached` events can be fired BEFORE the state updates.

Comment: Mmm maybe you are right. Try to use a combination of onEndReached and onMomentumScrollEnd with a simple variable instead of a state. For example: onEndReached={() => this.callOnScrollEnd = true}
onMomentumScrollEnd={() => {
  this.callOnScrollEnd && this.props.onEndReached()
  this.callOnScrollEnd = false
}

Comment: JS is single threaded. No need for mutexes. Are you storing `pageId` in a variable or in state?

Comment: @Wainage run this snack on an Android emulator, open the console logs and scroll the list back and forth multiple times. You will see that the event handlers execution process would overlap. https://snack.expo.io/@kolyunya/question---flat-list-concurrency

Comment: I see that but it is working correctly. You currently track no state. You need to keep track of what you are loading. Are the returned items large? If so, your state will have to manage the add / remove of items. If not, keep it all in your state object. Flatlist will only render items that are visible.

Comment: Another "hack" if your items keys are consistent, is to temporarily load "mock" items until the real ones arrive and overwrite the mock data. That way your list would grow naturally and each `onEndReach` would only be called once for each "page" of data. Facebook is fond of the "show-boxes-until-real-data-arrives" hack but we all use it for slow loading data

Comment: As stated by wainage, if you keep track of your request in a state you won't have problem: https://snack.expo.io/@nordup/question---flat-list-concurrency

Comment: i think you may be looking for throttle or debounce